# Proof that $\overline A= Int(A) \cup \partial (A)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to prove that $\overline A= Int(A) \cup \partial (A)$, My attempt is as follows.

For the first contention. Be $x\in \overline A$, then for all $r>0$ $B(x; r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and let $x \in Ext(A)=Int(M-A)$ i.e. exist $r>0$ such that $B(x;r) \subseteq A^{c}$ it follows that $A^{c}$ is open and $A$ closed.

How  $B(x;r) \subseteq A^{c}$ and $B(x; r) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ then $A^{c} \cap A \neq \emptyset$ which is not true, so $x$ is not an exterior point then subtract that $x$ is an interior point or point on the boundary of $A$.

Now, I'm having a little trouble seeing the other implication, any suggestions?

By the way, I am not using sequences in the process of the proof, only the definitions of closure, interior and boundary using open balls.

Comment: The statement that $x\in\text{Ext}(A)$ does not implay that $A^c$ is open.  Observe that $\text{Ext}(A)=\text{Int}(M\setminus A)=M\setminus\overline{A}$. Thus it only follows that $\overline{A}^c$ is open and therefore $\overline{A}$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with terms like closure/boundary/interior one should always give the definition one is working with as there are so many different and in some cases not even necessarily equivalent definitions out there. Let $A\subset\mathbb{R^n}$. I'll assume you use the following definitions as you mentioned open balls.

- We define the closure of $A$, denoted $\overline{A}$, by $\overline{A}:=\left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ B_r(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset\text{ for all }r>0\right\rbrace$
- We define the interior of $A$, denoted $\overset{\circ}{A}$, by $\overset{\circ}{A}:=\left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ \exists r>0:B_r(x)\subset A\right\rbrace$
- We define the boundary of $A$, denoted $\partial A$, by $\partial A:=\left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ \forall r>0:\left(B_r(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset\text{ and }B_r(x)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset\right)\right\rbrace$

We want to prove that $\overline{A}=\overset{\circ}{A}\cup\partial A$.
"$\subseteq$"
Let $x\in\overline{A}$, then by definition $B_r(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for all $r>0$. If $B_r(x)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$ for all $r>0$, then $x\in\partial A$ by definition. If $B_r(x)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$ is not true for all $r>0$, then there is some $r_1>0$ with $B_{r_1}(x)\cap A^c=\emptyset$. But this means that $B_{r_1}(x)\subset A$ and thus $x\in\overset{\circ}{A}$.
"$\supseteq$"
Let $x\in\overset{\circ}{A}\cup\partial A$. If $x\in\overset{\circ}{A}$, then there exists some $r>0$ with $B_r(x)\subset A$, which immediately implies that $B_r(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for all $r>0$ and thus $x\in\overline{A}$.
If $x\in\partial A$, then for all $r>0$ we have $B_r(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $B_r(x)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$, which is a stronger statement than $B_r(x)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for all $r>0$, which is equivalent to $x\in\overline{A}$. Thus we have proven the other inclusion as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,d_{X})$ be a metric space. Given a subset $A\subseteq X$, the following claims are equivalent:

(1) $x\in X$ is an adherent point of $A$.

(2) $x\in\text{Int}(A)\cup\partial A$.

(3) There is a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of points in $A$ such that $x_{n}\to x\in X$.

**Proof**

Let us begin with the implication $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$.

Suppose that $x\in X$ is an adherent point of $A$, but $x\not\in\text{Int}(A)\cup\partial A$. This means that $x\in\text{ext}(A)\subseteq A^{c}$, which is the same as to say that there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subseteq\text{ext}(A)\subseteq A^{c}$.

Consequently, we arrive at the following contradiction: $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap A = \varnothing$, and we are done.

Let us prove now that $(2)\Rightarrow(3)$.

If $x\in\text{Int}(A)$, then it suffices to consider the constant sequence $x_{n} = x$.

Suppose, otherwise, that $x\in\partial A$. Hence, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap A\neq\varnothing$ and $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap A^{c} \neq \varnothing$.

Let us stick with the first option in order to proceed.

This means that, for every $\varepsilon = 1/n$, there exists $x_{n}\in A$ s.t. $d_{X}(x_{n},x) \leq 1/n$. Therefore we conclude that $x_{n}\to x\in X$ due to the squeeze theorem and the definition of convergence of sequences in metric spaces.

Finally, we can handle the implication $(3)\Rightarrow(1)$.

The definition of convergence tell us that:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n} = x & \Longleftrightarrow (\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{X}(x_{n},x) < \varepsilon).
\end{align*}

This means that, no matter $\varepsilon > 0$ one chooses, there is always $x_{n_{\varepsilon}}\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)\cap A$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!